How to close multiprocessing pool inside process?
I am wondering how to make multiprocessing in python (3.11) with asynchronous calls (not asyncio lib) and automatically close processes when they are finished?
Below I wrote a simple code and the problem that it does not close pool processes (# this prints is never executed line are not reached), perhaps there are errors, but I don't see in terminal output (testing on Ubuntu).
Task: I need to execute processes every timer interval and without waiting to finish start new ones. I have not found any information on Internet and decided to make pool_list global variable to get access to pool objects (to close them later when process is done).
How to close pools correct in my problem? Maybe there is another solution? I chose concurrent.futures lib, because later I will need to start new pool process inside process (in func on_message), I have read that concurrent.futures can do that (source: Python multiprocessing: is it possible to have a pool inside of a pool?).
2024-06-01 02:53:23.984849 start
2024-06-01 02:53:23.987660 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:23.988430 new message: message-1, pool_list len=1

2024-06-01 02:53:28.988004 start
2024-06-01 02:53:28.991552 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:28.992286 new message: message-2, pool_list len=2

2024-06-01 02:53:33.991890 start
2024-06-01 02:53:33.994907 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:33.995735 new message: message-3, pool_list len=3
2024-06-01 02:53:38.988640 finished message: message-1

2024-06-01 02:53:38.995415 start
2024-06-01 02:53:38.998443 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:38.999227 new message: message-4, pool_list len=4
2024-06-01 02:53:43.992491 finished message: message-2

2024-06-01 02:53:43.999209 start
2024-06-01 02:53:44.002906 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:44.003642 new message: message-5, pool_list len=5
2024-06-01 02:53:48.995955 finished message: message-3

2024-06-01 02:53:49.003247 start
2024-06-01 02:53:49.006613 sleep 5 sec
2024-06-01 02:53:49.007651 new message: message-6, pool_list len=6
2024-06-01 02:53:53.999423 finished message: message-4
2024-06-01 02:53:59.003858 finished message: message-5
2024-06-01 02:54:04.007971 finished message: message-6

import time
import random
import string
from datetime import datetime
# from multiprocessing import Pool
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool


pool_list = {}

def on_message(pool_id, message):

    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} new message: {message}, pool_list len={len(pool_list)}")
    time.sleep(15)
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} finished message: {message}")
    # this prints is never executed
    print('done:', pool_list[pool_id].done())
    print('running:', pool_list[pool_id].running())
    # close pool as it finished
    pool_list[pool_id].cancel()
    del pool_list[pool_id]
    print('closed!', f"pool_list len={len(pool_list)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    for i in range(1, 7):
        print()
        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} start")
        pool_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=10))
        # we can not use "with" context, otherwise it will delay for loop until on_message() finished, but we need async
        pool = Pool(1)
        # adding pool to list in order to close() it in on_message()
        pool_list[pool_id] = pool
        pool.submit(on_message, pool_id, f'message-{i}')
        # or:
        # future = pool.submit(on_message, pool_id, f'message-{i}')
        # pool_list[pool_id] = future
        print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')} sleep 5 sec")
        time.sleep(5)

UPDATE: I wrapped on_message to try catch and pool_list is empty. No access to variable. So, how can I close pools?

You're trying to close the process that is being run.  How do you think that's going to work?

What is the context of your app? There might be better alternatives, for example, if you are utilizing for web (via Celery)

@TimRoberts In multiprocessing I could close with close() command. Anyway, when process is finished, I suppose I need to close pool. I don't know how

But you can't close the pool while you are executing as PART of that pool.

Why is it that almost nobody who posts a Python multiprocessing-related question specifies the platform they are running under like they are supposed to? If the spawn method is used to create child processes (e..g Windows), then onmessage will see an empty pool_list dictionary and raise a KeyError exception on expression pool_list[pool_id]. Is this relevant to you? Get rid of one or more of your redundant tags (e.g. python-3x and python-multiprocessing)` and include instead a tag for your platform.

Why are you creating a pool process of size 1 instead of just creating a multiprocessing.Process instance and why would a process try to terminate itself when it will terminate automatically when the on_message function call completes? I can see creating a single, multiprocessing pool of some size > 1 and then submitting tasks to onmessage where this will allow you to reuse child processes for subsequent messages. And cancel is not concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor method.

After tests I found out process will be closed automatically, otherwise close with os.kill(pid, 9)
